# how to write junit for below method which returns name of mongoDb

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

```
public String getMongoDBName() throws Exception {

return mongoConnectionDetails.getMongoDatabase().getName();

}
```

mongoConnectionDetails custom class is Autowired here.

What I tried is

```
Mock (mongoDboperation);

when(mongoConnectionDetails.getMongoDatabase().getName()).thenReturn("dbName");

String output = mongoDboperation.getMongoDBName();

assertEquals (output, "actualDBname");
```

But SONAR is still showing it as RED uncovered lines. Please help. Thanks !

Comment: if you are mocking mongoDboperation, it can't be an expected output

Comment: Unit testing "getter" methods has a very high cost benefit ratio.  Spend your time doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting coverage for this method, because you're running the test with a mock object. This means you are only testing the mock, not the original class.

In general, in the tests for a particular class, you should never mock the class that is being tested. Only mock collaborators of that class (in this case, `mongoConnectionDetails`.

Comment: So it’s a DAO class. You mean I should create DAO object with new or auto wiring and then mock dependencies , right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but I'd also agree with Dawood ibn Kareem's comment above that unit testing a DAO with mocks isn't that useful. The method above doesn't really have any logic or computation to test, so testing with a mock only verifies that it calls the method that it clearly calls in the source code. It doesn't prove that it actually works. It would be more useful to get coverage for this via integration tests that use an actual database.